# Installing vmware tools on Ubuntu host?

Tags: 14.04, virtualization, vmware-player, vmware-tools

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit, and using vmware player to run Windows 7 32 bit as guest with vmware tools installed.

I can't get the shared clipboard to run!

I found that I must also install vmware tools on the host (Ubuntu). How can I install vmware tools on Ubuntu 14.04 ?

I tried to download the deb package from vmware website but I didn't find a version for 14.04. When I browsed older versions of Ubuntu I found about thirty `.deb` packages. I don't know which I must download.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you link to the site where it is said that you have to install on host as well? I can't find any mention of installing on the host in VMWare docs (like http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1035392).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get the shared clipboard to work on Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/482503/cant-get-the-shared-clipboard-to-work-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score -2):

download the VM workstation

http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/

```
chmod +x VMware-Workstation-Full-10.0.1-1379776.i386.bundle 
sh VMware-Workstation-Full-10.0.1-1379776.i386.bundle
```

the continue the installation